# SSRS Report Builder: showing detailed data in the middle of a report, "within" a parent group

Tags: reporting-services, grouping

I've been struggeling with this issue for a while now and can't seem to figure it out.

Is it possible in SSRS to have a parent group in my report, then some data in a child group, and then to the right of that columns some more data grouped the same way as the parent group? Parent groups automatically appear on the left of my report, how do I get one on the right so that my report looks something like this:
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MpdAR.png)

So I want the data in column 4 to be grouped the same way as columns 1 and 2. Is this possible?

Hope you can help, thanks!

Comment: I don't think this is possible the way the parent and child grouping is set up. If you need something like this, I think the best (only?) way would be to have the child records as a sub report in column 3.

Comment: It looks like all columns have the same number of cells. All cells are populated in column 3, however, columns 1, 2, & 4 have several cells left empty. Have you tried using empty values?

Comment: I agree with Hannover, the only way I know to do this is to create a really small subreport and use that in the column 3 . Note that you would no longer need the detailed rows, you would only need the parent level in your main report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get this behavior by having two tables next to each other. "Column 4" from your example would be the first column of the second table. Both tables would be grouped the same way. The trick to getting the second table to have the same height is to still include a details group. So the second table will still have another column that is grouped, but you can make it invisible.

Here is an example of the design for the layout:
[image]

And here is the result:

[image]