# I am attempting to add a column to an SSRS tablix that must be within a column group but outside of a row group

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I currently have a tablix that contains a column that is outside all column and row groups. I'm using this as a Header to create an element that spans multiple rows in order to display as a "grouping". I need this grouping to iterate through columns as well. I cannot seem to, however, add a column that is inside the column group, but outside the row group.

What I would like to have is a tablix where all columns are contained within the column group, but not all columns are part of the row group. Is this possible?

Current Tablix Layout:

[image: Tablix Layout]

Current Display:

[image: Tablix Display]

Edited for more information:

Currently the output basically looks like this:

[image]

I want the output to look like this, where the Header does not repeat with the rows but does repeat with Column Group 1:

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what you want your new structure to look like. Could you mock up an image of what you expect the final output to look like vs the current output

Comment: I've updated the question to include a clearer version of what I want the output to look like, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68368475/2033717). In order to get subsequent row headers to span multiple rows, you have to use another table. The tables should be row-grouped on the same fields so that they maintain the same height and appear to be one congruent table.

Now, if you want this setup to be more dynamic where there are a variable number of tables, you can control this using column groups. It sounds like this is what you are actually looking for. So you would have one table with the desired layout. Then put that entire table inside another table. The outer table would have the column group. This way, the inner table gets repeated, headers and all, for each value in the column group.

Nesting tables is a little tricky at first, but offers a lot of flexibility with complex layouts.

Comment: Although this is tricky it is probably the simplest way to do this. @Aaron There is no way produce the layout you want with a single tablix so you have to use more creative method like this.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know how many columns I need, this is supposed to be a dynamic output.

Let's say that Column Group 1 is "Location" and Column Group 2 is "Year"
Right now it will iterate those fine for every row, but the first column, containing the row-spanning header, is not part of the "Location" column group. Is there no way to have a column that is part of a column group but not part of a row group in that tablix?

Comment: It's difficult to visualize these details since they weren't in the original question. When you say "part of", it's not clear if you mean grouped by or just happens to be in a cell in the table. Also, it's not clear if you're grouping location on rows or columns. These kinds of specifications would be better off in a new question. Hopefully the technique I introduced makes sense for how to design more complex table layouts in general.